# Can I find a better solution of $\sin(x^2 + x) = \frac 1 2$ for $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

It's obvious that
$$x^2 + x = (-1)^k \arcsin \frac 1 2 + \pi k$$
where $k \in \Bbb Z$.

If I treat $(-1)^k \arcsin \frac 1 2 + \pi k$ as a constant, I get the answer: $$x_{1, 2} = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4(-1)^k \arcsin \frac 1 2 + \pi k}} {2}$$ The ugliness and length of the answer makes me think I did something wrong.

Background: Knowing the structure of my textbook, I think authors didn't expect me to use [addition and subtraction theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_addition_formula#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities). Also note that this is a preparation for a college entrance exam.

Comment: I have an unpleasant feeling they are working in degrees.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't remember the last time I was asked to solve a trigonometric equation in degrees. I'm not even sure if it's done in a way I think it is.

Answer (score 5):

Why not treat $(\frac\pi6+2k\pi)$and $(\frac{5\pi}6+2k\pi)$ as a constant and use the quadratic formula?

Comment: I've reformulated my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out that this is actually a **wrong** answer since I say that $k \in \Bbb Z$.

It made me no good that I shortened the answer to a single line. Let's take a look at the expanded version:
$$ x = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \frac \pi 6 + 2 \pi k}} {2} \tag{1}$$
$$ x = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \frac {5 \pi} 6 + 2 \pi k}} {2} \tag{2}$$
Now I can see that there are certain restrictions:
$$ 1 + \frac \pi 6 + 2 \pi k \ge 0 $$
$$ 1 + \frac {5 \pi} 6 + 2 \pi k \ge 0 $$
For $k \ge 0$, the inequality holds. One can check that this is not true for $k \le -1$.

So the answer is the expressions $(1), (2)$ where $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, …$

So yes, I can find a better solution (because the right solution is better than the wrong one). 
I suppose this was the catch of the exercise.

Comment: first off, you forgot to multiply the constant by 4. And then, it works for negative k. Take $k=-2$. Then $x=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+2\pi/3-8\pi})=(-1+i\sqrt{22\pi/3-1})/2$, which is a root of the equation. See http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%5E2%2Bx%29%2C+x%3D%28-1%2B%5Csqrt%7B1%2B2%5Cpi%2F3-8%5Cpi%7D%29%2F2&x=0&y=0